# How to title/name each fragment separately to appear on PagerTitleStrip?

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

[image: Each Fragment displaying its own title/name]

How to title/name each fragment so that their respective names appear on the [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override [getPageTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageTitle%28int%29) in your PagerAdapter class and set the title according to the position of the fragments.

```
@Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) 
        {

            switch(position)
            {
            case 0 : return "Movies";
            case 1 : return "Music";
            case 2 : return "Games!";
            }
            return "Easy";  //this wont be executed
        }
```